# mapStateToProps don't send anything to props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component "FloatingChat" which needs to be connected to Redux,
So I created a container "FloatingChatContainer" for this component,

src/containers/FloatingChatContainer.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import FloatingChat from "../../components/FloatingChat";

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  auth: state[props.auth],
  errors: state[props.errors]
});

const FloatingChatContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(FloatingChat);

export default FloatingChatContainer;
```

But, in the FloatingChat component, I have an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("props ", props);
    if (props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      loadUser();
    }
  }, []);
```

And the console log returns an empty object, so my props aren't arrived in the component,

Someone help ?

Comment: Are you actually using the connected version of the component?  I've seen a number of people accidentally import and use the "plain" version.

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing `auth: state[props.auth],` and not just `auth: state.auth`, in `mapStateToProps`? For `auth: state[props.auth],` to make sense you'd need to be rendering `FloatingChatContainer` with its own `auth` prop that is the name of the key in `state` which maps to the `auth` state you care about which seems confusing or at the very least unorthodox.

Comment: hello, before it was working because I did the mapStateToProps and the connect in the component, but I was told that it's not good, and that I have to separate the component and make it a container.. I have a reducer with a isAuthenticated property inside the state

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer what's going on with your state without seeing more of your project. I'd look at a few different potential culprits though:

1. Make sure your component is taking in props via `constructor(props)` + `super(props)`.
2. Add logger middleware to your application so that you can trace your state/debug errors better. You can look at logger [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger).
3. Add a `componentDidMount()` method to your react component.

Comment: hello, i'm using functional components with hooks, so I don't have constructor, super and componentDidMount :)

Comment: Hey! Best practice for react hooks is to not use containers. Dan Abramov discusses this in his update [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). Also, [here](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) are the redux docs on integrating react hooks - hope that helps!